# Setting up an IMAP e-mail, need help

Tags: email, imap, stock-email-app, motorola-electrify

I am  trying to link my college e-mail to my android phone.  I have all the info for the IMAP server and Port but when it says "Checking incoming server setting" it comes back with a box that says "Username or password incorrect".... The problem is I know I am putting in the right password.

I have a Motorola Electrify 2 that runs Android 4.0.4. (ice cream sandwich). I am using the stock e-mail setup.

Here's the info from my school for setting up the email:

**Incoming settings**

IMAP server: imap.gmail.com

Port:993

Security: SSL (always)

**Outgoing settings**

SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com

Port: 463 or 587

Security: SSL (always)

THANKS!

Comment: Try to change your Security to "SSL If Possible", change the port of your outgoing settings to "465" and my servers aren't "...gmail.com" but "...googlemail.com". If this does not work I'm out.

Comment: Are you using your full email address as your username? Do you have an alternate email address at your college? If so, have you tried using that as your username?